# read date from a file and return a string of month, date, year

Tags: java

I would greatly appreciate any input...  I have researched and tried a million different thing...thank you in advance!!!
I have to read an input file to create an address book based on the given file.  The file consists of 12 contacts and is in the format below.( I have scanner and all set up in testAddressBook and all looks good... not including that whole file but basic part where I set up Scanner is as follows)

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class testAddressBook
 {
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("AddressBook.txt"));
    //inFile.useDelimiter( "[/\n]" );  tried this but doesn't work


    AddressBook myMembers = new AddressBook(inFile);

    inFile.close(); //InFile.close();
```

Input file format looks like this...

```
12      //this is an int at the beginning of the file that says how many contacts I have
Rodgers Katie   //this is last and first name
12/09/1999       //this is their birthdate
1 Main St APT 6          //this is their street address
Taunton                   //this is their city
MA 02108 (509)245-1489          //this is state zipcode and phone numb
Family                         //this is their relationship to me
Malik Shelly         //next person in contact file...  ect...
12/08/2000
100 Lincoln Drive
Omaha
NE 68131 (402)555-1212
Friend
ect....
```

I have to bring this into a class ExtPerson, which is a class that extends Person(string name -last and first), Address(all strings of street, city, state, zipcode, phone), Date (can be a string or int of -month, day, year), and ExtPerson also creates a variable to store how this person is known to me, whether a friend, family, or business contact. This needs to be an ordered list and I have to be able to sort on how they are related, input new contacts, and perform various other functions from a menu including sort birthday.  I am having trouble with reading the date from the file which is in format 12/02/1999, and returning month, day, year as three separate things -removing the slashes in between the  month day and year . I am required to have all three separate.  I have tried numerous things, but cannot get anything to work.  Here is my code for three of the six classes in my program that use this date...  My problem is in the class AddressBook when I am reading in the file it breaks when I get to try to read in birthday date  not sure how to read this in and store

First class is Date: //I am required to have it set up this way though variables can be int or string
                        //think I'd rather int but no big deal either way
    public class Date
    {
    private String dMonth;
    private String dDay;
    private String dYear;
    //private String bday;  try..

```
public Date()
    {

dMonth = "";
dDay = "";
dYear = "";
}

public Date(String month, String day, String year)
{   
dMonth = month;
dDay = day;
dYear = year;
}

public void setDate(String month, String day, String year)//had to add void..
{   
dMonth = month;
dDay = day;
dYear = year;
}

   public String getMonth()
{   
return dMonth;

}
   public String getDate()
{   
return dDay;

}
   public String getYear()
{   
return dYear;

}

   public String getDate(String month, String day, String year)
{
return (dMonth + "-" +dDay + "-" +dYear);
}
```

}

Next class is ExtPerson....

```
 //THIS CLASS EXTENDS PERSON,DATE,ADDRESS

  public class ExtPerson 

  {
private Person name;
private Date bDay; 
private Address address;
private String relationship;

public ExtPerson()
      {
name= new Person ();
bDay = new Date();
address = new Address();
relationship = "";
 }

public ExtPerson(String last, String first, String month, String day, String
      year, String street, String city, String state, String zipcode, String phone, String
      relateby)
      {

name= new Person (first, last);
bDay = new Date(month, day, year);
address = new Address (street, city,state,zipcode,phone);
relationship = relateby;

      }

     //methd to set personal info. instance variables are set according to parameters


     public void setMemberInfo(String last, String first, String month, String day, String 
     year, String street, String city, String state, String zipcode, String phone,String 
     relateby)
{
    name.setName(last, first);
    bDay.setDate(month, day, year);
    address.setAddress(street, city,state,zipcode,phone);
    relationship = relateby;
 }

public void setRelationship(String relateby)
{
    relationship = relateby;
}

public boolean isRelationship(String relateby)
{
    return (relationship.equals(relateby));
}

public String getRelationship()
{
    return relationship;
}
public Person getMembername()
{
    return name;
}
public void printRelationship()
{
    System.out.println("Relationship: " + relationship);
}

public void printInfo()
{
    System.out.println ("Name: " + name.toString()); 
    System.out.println ("Date of birth: " + bDay.toString ());
    System.out.println ("Address: " + address.toString()); 
    System.out.println ("Relationship: " + relationship.toString());
}
```

}

And last class AddressBook where I read all these name into using a filereader: THIS IS WHERE ERROR COMES WHEN GET TO BIRTHDAY

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class AddressBook
 {
 int nMembers;//in the beginning of infile, there is an int that says how many people are 
                      in the file
 ExtPerson[] bookMembers = new ExtPerson[500];


 public AddressBook(Scanner inFile )
 {
    String last, first, street, city, state, zipcode,phone, relateby;
    String month,day,year;
    //int month, day, year;  not sure if I'm better off with int or string for 
                           these..


    nMembers = inFile.nextInt();
    inFile.nextLine(); //discard the newline character


    for (int index = 0; index < nMembers; index++)
    {
        bookMembers[index] = new ExtPerson();

        first =  inFile.next();
        last =  inFile.next();


                  //HERE IS MY PROBLEM.. BIRTHDATE IS IN FILE LIKE 12/04/1999
                  // THE CLASS DATE MUST INCLUDE A MONTH, DATE, YEAR
                  //I MUST RETURN THIS WITH THOSE THREE BUT DON'T KNOW HOW TO STRIP THEM OUT

              ??  bday = inFile.nextLine(); //TAKE AS STRING AND SOMEHOW IN ANOTHER CLASS 
                                                  BREAK IT DOWN LATER??
        //or ??
                month = inFile.next();//CAN I SOMEHOW STRIP IT DOWN NOW TO STORE FOR THIS INDEX
        day = inFile.next();            
        year = inFile.next();

        street =  inFile.nextLine();
        city =  inFile.nextLine();
        state =  inFile.next();
        zipcode =  inFile.next();
        phone =  inFile.next();
        relateby =  inFile.nextLine();
        //amount = inFile.nextDouble();
        inFile.nextLine(); //discard the newline character
        bookMembers[index].setMemberInfo(first,last, 
                   month,day,year,street,city,state,zipcode,phone,relateby);
    }
    insertionSort();
 }

 public void printInfo()
 {
     for (int index = 0; index < nMembers; ++ index)
         bookMembers[index].printInfo();
 }

 public void insertionSort()
 {
        int location;
        ExtPerson temp = new ExtPerson();

        for (int firstOutOfOrder = 1; firstOutOfOrder < nMembers;
                                      firstOutOfOrder++)
            if (bookMembers[firstOutOfOrder].getMembername().compareTo(bookMembers   
                      [firstOutOfOrder - 1].getMembername())<0)
            {
                temp = bookMembers[firstOutOfOrder];
                location = firstOutOfOrder;

                do
                {
                    bookMembers[location] = bookMembers[location - 1];
                    location--;
                }
                while (location > 0 && (bookMembers[location - 1].getMembername().compareTo
                     (temp.getMembername())<0));

                bookMembers[location] = temp;
            }
  } //end insertionSort

 public void endOfDay(PrintWriter outFile)
 {
        outFile.println (nMembers);

        for (int index = 0; index < nMembers; index++)
        {
            outFile.println(bookMembers[index].getMembername());

            outFile.println(bookMembers[index].getRelationship());
            //ECT..FINISH LATER
        }

 }  // end endOfDay

 public int binarySearch(Person searchArg)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = nMembers - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    boolean found = false;

    while (first <= last && !found)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if (bookMembers[mid].getMembername().compareTo(searchArg) == 0)
                found = true;
        else if (bookMembers[mid].getMembername().compareTo(searchArg) > 0)
                last = mid - 1;
             else
                first = mid + 1;
    }

    if (!found)
        mid = -1; //it is an unsuccessful search

    return mid;
}//end binarySearch
```

....NEED TO FINISH WRITING ALL MENU DRIVEN OPTIONS ECT...
    }

Comment: Just too long, which people don't like to read through - can you condense it and put the exact issue here ?

Comment: As user2314533 said, you have a duty to debug your code enough to determine exactly the point of failure. Write a separate app to demonstrate the problem. Extract that problem code to a separate method or app to verify your problem by feeding it a specific input string, and *then* post a question here. P.S. If your question is how to extract parts of a date from a string, look at [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to create a DateTime object, then extract the month name or number, etc. by calling various methods. P.P.S. The format of that data file is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` method ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)) on the `String` object, like this:

```
String bday = inFile.nextLine();
String[] parts = bday.split("/");
Date d = new Date(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
```

Comment: When I do this I get an output to the console like this:

Comment: Name:  
Date of birth: Date@6916c054
Address:   Relationship: 
    Name:  
    Date of birth: Date@54ad00b2
    Address:   
    Relationship: 
    Name:  
    Date of birth: Date@2a08d18c
    Address:   
    Relationship: 
    Name:  
    Date of birth: Date@28f553e3
    Address:   
    Relationship:

Comment: That's not a bug in my code. That's a bug in your code. You need to implement the `toString` method.

Comment: Date d = new Date(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);

Comment: my date class is set up as date (month, day year). Does doing it this way mean I need to change my whole date class to date(parts[], parts[], parts[]) instead? I think I was not supposed to alter the date class but not sure that's possible.

Comment: No, it does not. `parts[0]` is an individual string, not an array.